# In a rails controller, how do I address the current object within the create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, controller

I'd like the creation of a Window to generate a number of Timeslots that belong to it. It's pretty easy to take an integer from a form object and create that many timeslots, but I can't figure out how to grab the window ID to tell the timeslots who they belong to.

```
def create
  @window = Window.new(window_params)

  @window.capacity.times do
    if Timeslot.last
    then
      @newID = Timeslot.last.id += 1
    else
     @newID = 1
    end
    @timeslot = Timeslot.new({id: @newID})
    @timeslot.created_at = Time.now
    @timeslot.window_id = @window.id
    @timeslot.save
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @window.save
      format.html { redirect_to @window, notice: 'Window was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @window }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @window.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

If anyone can point me to a more elegant way to find a new Timeslot ID, I'd appreciate it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@window` will not have an ID until after it is saved to the database. Therfore, create timeslots after the record is saved. I extracted timeslot creation to its own private method that gets called after save.

```
def create
  @window = Window.new(window_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @window.save
      create_timeslots  # <-- timeslot creation performed after save
      format.html { redirect_to @window, notice: 'Window was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @window }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @window.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

def create_timeslots
  @window.capacity.times do
    Timeslot.create({window_id: @window.id})
  end
end
```

I removed the code which sets timeslot ID and creation time because ActiveRecord does it already. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Oh, brilliant. I guessed that ID wasn't created until the object was saved, but I wasn't sure. Thanks a bunch!